# Log where permissions are being refused?

Tags: 6, users

When not logged in as admin my view is returning no results. I believe it to be a permissions issue but everything appears to be configured correctly.

Is there a way to get a log of what permissions are being attempted and then rejected, and by what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Permissions usually are checked by a function call to `user_access` and for performance reasons there is no way to override that (not that D6 was so big on overrides like D7 is -- still that function can't be overridden in D7). You can set use devel to see the query if one is run or Views can display the query. As a last resort, you can add `error_log(4, $string);` into `user_access` itself to send the permissions into Apache error log or similar.

Note that it can be a node access issue, in this case the query log will help you.